# mysql utf8mb4 doesnt seems to be updated after i've edit

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

This is the image which i have try to work but not working this, so please help me.

[image]

Comment: show your code which try ? other wise we can not help properly

Comment: Hi, which code are you refering to ? the eclipse ones works perfectly until certain emoji is being place in

Answer (score 0):

`character_set_client/connection/results` are the three that need to be set to `utf8mb4` so that `INSERTs` and `SELECTs` handle full UTF-8 to/from the clients.

And you need `utf8mb4` for Emoji and some of Chinese; `utf8` will not suffice.

Comment: i've tried many ways online t set those 3 to utf8mb4 but it doens't work

Comment: Right after connecting, do `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.  Note:  user=root ignores `init_connect` in `my.cnf`.